# Entity Framework Model Properties Not Created On Update-Database Command

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I recently needed to change the ***type*** of three properties in a model class from string to an ICollection custom type as shown below.

There are also three classes (SpecialType, TypeToAdd, TypeToRemove) that were added that have a primary key ID, name (string), qty (int) and a FK to corresponding Subscriptions_Regular_Id.

I ran the migration, then update-database to script, but when I ran the script in SSMS console it left off the three ICollection properties below.  It did create the three dependent tables with their foreign keys back to the parent, but I can't understand why it's not creating these three ICollection properties.  Something simple I'm overlooking I'm sure and wanted to get some input if anyone might have a suggestion.

```
    public class Subscriptions
{
    [Key]
    public int Subscriptions_Regular_Id { get; set; }
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int TypeQty { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SpecialType> SpecialType { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TypeToAdd> TypeToAdd { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TypeToRemove> TypeToRemove { get; set; }
}
```

For context:
Subscriptions can have many SpecialTypes, TypeToAdd, and TypeToRemove
SpecialTypes, TypeToAdd, TypeToRemove can be tied to only one Subscription.

Thanks in advance for any input.

====== EDIT ======
Adding 3 ICollection classes:

```
    public class TypeToAdd
{
    [Key]
    public int TypeToAddId { get; set; }
    public string TypeToAdd { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public int Subscriptions_Regular_Id { get; set; }
    public Subscriptions Subscriptions { get; set; }
}
```

The other two classes are the same as above other than the first two property names (they are TypeToRemove and SpecialType).

Comment: I believe you need to add those new types to your `DbContext` implementation. You should also be able to look at the actual migration (<timestamp>_<migration-name>.cs) to see what it will do on migration.

Comment: Please post SpecialType TypeToAdd  TypeToRemove classes

Comment: "I can't understand why it's not creating these three ICollection properties." - what type do you think these properties should be in data base?

Comment: Your ICollections should be virtual so you can access them in the parent object. With that said, they will never appear in your database. If you want to add them as FK constraints, use the model builder inside your dbcontext.

Comment: @Serge I posted the other classes as you requested.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you post Subscriptions_Regular too pls?

Comment: @Serge Perhaps I made a mistake using ICollection type.  What I'm wanting is for Subscriptions to be able to contain multiple SpecialType, TypeToAdd, and TypeToRemove properties.

Comment: @Serge Sorry Subscriptions_Regular was a copy/paste error.  The class is just Subscriptions and it's above in my original post.  Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I can't understand why it's not creating these three ICollection properties

Collection Navigation Properties are implemented using seperate tables with foreign keys.  Relational databases don't have multi-valued attributes, so that's just how related collections are implemented in an RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks @David Brown...I had done this before with a Product to Category type relationship and the two tables were created with necessary keys and foreign keys, and the .net mvc scaffolding even accounted for the Category type with a drop down in the "create and edit" controller actions.  EF is not my strong point as you can see.  Thanks for the input.  :)

Comment: after thinking this through, I see that it will not work as I was envisioning.  In terms of a plain model or viewmodel my classes would be fine with these props but not for a relational db.  I will proceed with separate tables for the previous ICollection props and have a FK that ties them to the main class.  I'll just have to account for those in my LINQ queries to get all related values.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the classes to this

```
   public class Subscription
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int TypeQty { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(TypeToAdd.Subscription))]
  public ICollection<TypeToAdd> TypeToAdds { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(SpecialType.Subscription))]
    public virtual  ICollection<SpecialType> SpecialTypes { get; set; }
  
    [InverseProperty(nameof(TypeToRemove.Subscription))]
    public ICollection<TypeToRemove> TypeToRemoves { get; set; }
}

    public class TypeToAdd
   {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TypeToAdd { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }

    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(SubscriptionId))]
    [InverseProperty("TypeToAdds")]
    public virtual Subscription Subscription { get; set; }
}
```

SpecialType and TypeToRemove classes should be configured the same way as TypeToAdd.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...good thought and it makes sense but it didn't add the properties I need.  The more I think through this the more I see the answer below is correct, what I'm wanting will not work.  It'll work for a plain model or viewmodel class but not for a database field.